# How to Union two different conditions in one WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I need to query **in one WP_Query**:

**All posts that are children of category id = 6** and also **the posts in category 7 but only those that have been checked a custom field of ACF (true / false)**.

In SQL would be like:

```
$querystr= "SELECT r.term_taxonomy_id, p.*
        FROM  $wpdb->posts p, $wpdb->term_relationships r
        WHERE r.object_id = p.ID
        and r.term_taxonomy_id = 6

        UNION ALL

        SELECT r.term_taxonomy_id, p.*
        FROM  $wpdb->posts p, $wpdb->term_relationships r, $wpdb->postmeta pm
        WHERE r.object_id = p.ID
         and r.term_taxonomy_id = 7
         and pm.post_id = p.ID
         and pm.meta_key = 'visible_para_organizadores'
         and pm.meta_value = '1'

    ";
```

**All queried posts posts must be 6 in total and must be paged and ordered by date**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This isn't possible in WP_Query. It's not possible to only apply a meta query to posts from one category out of several being queried. You'll need multiple queries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jacob. And how can I do that? because posts have to be ordered by date and paged.

Comment: It would be quite difficult. A *far* simpler option would be to create a category/taxonomy term that you apply to all the posts you want to show, then just query that.

Comment: Yes, I thought that alternative. But I wanted to do by the first way. 
I'm going to create the taxonomy, is easier and faster.
@JacobPeattie I have a question for you. Looking for an answer y found that: https://github.com/birgire/wp-combine-queries. What do you think about? Just for knowing.
Thanks a lot

Comment: I haven’t tried it, but if it says it does what you need go ahead and give it a go. But you can see what I meant by it being complicated.